# How to create a credential (for google sheets) on GCE with php code?

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I put my php code in GCE and wanna to modify google sheets.
Google told me that i don't have to apply a extra credential by using GCP>API because there's a strategy called Application Default Credentials (ADC) will find application's credentials.
I first check the environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" in GCE server but it's empty.
Then i follow this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production?hl=zh_TW#auth-cloud-implicit-php and install this:

```sh
composer require google/cloud-storage
```

I tried the code under and got some error.

```php
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Auth;

// Imports GCECredentials and the Cloud Storage client library.
use Google\Auth\Credentials\GCECredentials;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

function auth_cloud_explicit_compute_engine($projectId)
{
    $gceCredentials = new GCECredentials();
    $config = [
        'projectId' => $projectId,
        'credentialsFetcher' => $gceCredentials,
    ];
    $storage = new StorageClient($config);

    # Make an authenticated API request (listing storage buckets)
    foreach ($storage->buckets() as $bucket) {
        printf('Bucket: %s' . PHP_EOL, $bucket->name());
    }
}
```

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'GCECredentials' not found in /var/www/html/google_sheets/t2.php:5

More question:
Will this code create a json file as credential for me to access google sheets?

```php
$gceCredentials = new GCECredentials();
```

Or where can i find the service account key??
Please tell me what should i do, thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to include the Composer autoload file: `include 'vendor/autoload.php';`. There is no need to provide the GCECredentials instance. Google Cloud PHP will detect that your application is running in GCE and authenticate automatically.

Comment: The sample code you're using will not help you authenticate against the Sheets API, however. To authenticate with Sheets, take a look at the PHP Quickstart for Sheets: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

Comment: @jdp Yes, i have already achieved this developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php . And i'm asking for where can i get the Credentials.json in GCE for GCE default (which means i don't have to apply in GCP>APIs&Services>Credentials).